# How to read a list of data-files in order to use variables in GNUplot?

Tags: linux, file, gnuplot

I work in a Linux PC. I need to fit each data-file from a file-list (a few hundred) in a list-file(txt) in Gnuplot.

When I use my "gnu-fitting script" for such multiple files in a list-file, how to read each file-name in the list-file(txt) and extract the variables in each data file(txt) into my gnu-fitting script?

I prefer to use it in my gnu-script! but if possible please let me know any possible shell script.

So, I need to know how to make... "a loop-process" to read file-names in a list-file so as to do the same-fitting-process for many data files in the list 
 easily~!

e.g.) Something like [do ... while] for Gnuplot to consecutively read many data file names from a list file.

Is it possible in Gnuplot??

Thanks.

===

@ I have a gnu-fitting script (let's say a simple numerical-function) working for a single data file now.

However, In the script, I have to specify "the name of data file" each time in my current script.

But, I'd like to know how to apply this script with a loop-process for many numerous data-files specified in a list-file automatically.

So I'd like to know how to implement this loop-process in gnu-script.
   I need to do Something like... in C-language in my gnu-scipt;

@ Do, [read a data-file in a list-file], [run a gnu-ftting] while (eof).

@A: A simple Gnu-fitting-script.
@B: A list-file containing many data-file names in each line.

By running the "A", I have to deal with all the data-files in "B" consecutively ...!!

That is my point.

Is it helpful to understand??
Thanks.

For example,

"fit f(x) "Test001.dat" u 1:2 via a,b,c"

Usually, I have to specify "the name" of the data file like this~!!

But, I need to apply the same-fitting process from "Test0001.dat" up to Test1000.dat~!! (1000-files consecutively~!)

So, 2-main questions~!!

@How to do it in Gnuplot to read the file-name in a loop??
@How to make the name of data-file as a variable in the script??

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is or what you are asking. Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error you are experiencing. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK. Sorry for my short English... I'd like to make an automatic-fitting results using my "gnu-script" for many data-files in a list-file, which has the same format. The problem is that I do not know how to read and import the data in the numerous files listed in a list-file. So, I'd like to automatically read the file name in each line of the list-file and try to use the data in each file for my fitting script.

Comment: My gnu-script is working well for fitting for a single data file~!! However, I'd like to make it an automatic-process for the numerous files in a list-file. In this case, how to read the file name in the list file and import the data as variables into my gnu-script?? That is my point~!!

Comment: So, I need to implement "a loop-process" to read a file-name from a list-file(txt) and extract those data into my gnuplot-fitting-script which is currently working only for a "single file-name" already written in my script.

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I need to get 1,000 fitting graphs automatically using a list-file~!!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, the following might be a starting point...

```
### loop in gnuplot with generating filename
reset session

myFile(n) = sprintf("Test%04d.dat", n)
f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c

do for [i=1:1000] {
    fit f(x) myFile(i) u 1:2 via a,b,c
    print a, b, c
    # or do something else...
}
### end of code
```

**Addition:**

```
### loop certain files in a directory
reset session

myFileList = system('ls Test*.dat')      # Linux
myFileList = system('dir /b Test*.dat')  # Windows

f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c

do for [myFile in myFileList] {
    fit f(x) myFile u 1:2 via a,b,c
    print a, b, c
    # or do something else...
}
### end of code
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. I got it~!!

Comment: another point~? instead of using "sprintf", can I use a list file? (e.g. List = system( "./ls Test-*.dat")...then how to extract each line as a variable(file name) in a loop?? it seems "word(List, i)" is not working... in my case.